# QComboBox Look Changes When I Use setEditable(true)

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qlineedit, appearance

I wanted to center align text items in a QComboBox but to do this I need to set Editable to true.  When I do this the look changes significantly. This is on Windows 7.

[QComboBox when setEditable(false)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAZou.jpg)

[QComboBox when setEditable(true)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvvWk.jpg)

I think the change happens because QLineEdit has a different default appearance than QComboBox. What can I do to get them both to look the same?   Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When you enable the editable state of the QComboBox the default widget change to a QEditText so you have to edit the QEditText style using [Qt Style Sheet](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html):

```
QLineEdit* lineEdit = new QLineEdit(parent);
lineEdit->setStyleSheet("here customize");
lineEdit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter)
ui->combo->setLineEdit(lineEdit);
```

If you want no editable line edit, try this:

```
lineEdit->setReadOnly(true);
ui->combo->setLineEdit(lineEdit);
ui->combo->setEditable(true);
```

An alternative, you can customize your own QComboBox and modify the `paintEvent(...)`.

Comment: Thank you.  I kind of figured that but I am at a loss as to how to figure out the default style settings for the un-editable QComboBox so I can apply them to the editable QComboBox.  I did set the read-only true but it still gave me the different look.